# Rails: Naming conventions for attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, naming-conventions

Im creating a model with the line

```
rails g scaffold contact firstname:string lastname:string email:string
```

But should the attributes be like

```
first_name:string
```

instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Conventions aren't set in stone, but it's good to follow them.

And yes, widely spread convention for attribute names is [snake case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case).

> #### Snake case:
>
> punctuation is removed and spaces are replaced by single underscores. Normally the letters share the same case (either UPPER_CASE_EMBEDDED_UNDERSCORE or lower_case_embedded_underscore) but the case can be mixed.

Comment: Thanks. As a noob I think I should stay as strict as possible. Also scared to break some of these now and then break my app. (and/or my understanding)

Comment: @Jepzen excellent policy and makes it much easier for others to read and understand your code

Answer (score 2):

Attributes should be in snake_case hands down. For more details on proper Rails coding style refer to the [exhaustive Rails 3 style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide).